# where should control-system problem be asked

Tags: discussion

I have a control-system program in MATLAB in which I am stuck . I am not able to decide on which site I should I ask the question math.stackexchange or stackoverflow.com or electronics.stackexchange.com .

Comment: What exactly is the question? Mathematics questions belong here, coding questions belong on stackoverflow etc. If you want us to help decide which forum your question belongs in, show us the question!